# Kendo Grid, Hierarchy template filled by data without additional request.

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I would like to ask, how can i add some data into inner table using hierarchy template in Kendo grid component?.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

I would like to append newly added data in inner table as array of the objects into the existing object which is filled in outer table.

In demo example is read request processed a twice, but i would like to process CRUD oprations as single request.

Thanks for any help.

[image]